# Prove: if $f:\mathbb{N} \rightarrow A, g:\mathbb{N} \rightarrow B$ are surjections, there exists a surjection $h:\mathbb{N} \rightarrow A \cup B$

Tags: proof-verification, alternative-proof, proof-explanation, elementary-functions

I chose my own sets here for A and B as countably infinite pairwise disjoint subsets of $\mathbb{N}$. Can I do this with finite subsets and get an easier answer with the same result?

---

Suppose $A = \mathbb{N}_e$ such that $\mathbb{N}_e$ is the set of all even natural numbers. $\mathbb{N}_e \subset \mathbb{N}$

Also suppose $B = \mathbb{N}_o$ such that $\mathbb{N}_o$ is the set of all odd natural numbers. $\mathbb{N}_o \subset\mathbb{N}$

$\mathbb{N}_e \cup \mathbb{N}_o = \mathbb{N}$

$h: \mathbb{N} \rightarrow A \cup B$ is given by

$h(x) = $

$f(\frac{x}{2})$ if $x\in \mathbb{N}_e$

$g(\frac{x+1}{2})$ if $x\in \mathbb{N}_o$

Let $n \in \mathbb{N}$. If $n \in \mathbb{N}_e$, consider $x = 2n$

$f(x) = \frac{2n}{2} = n$

Let $n \in \mathbb{N}$. If $n \in \mathbb{N}_o$, consider $x = 2n-1$

$g(x) = \frac{(2n-1)+1}{2} = n$

So $h: \mathbb{N} \rightarrow A \cup B$ is surjective.

---

I'm kind of iffy on notation here. I'm wondering when it came to constructing the $h$ function, why it wasn't $f(x)$ if $x \in A$ or something like that. I get these two different things confused all of the time.

---

UPDATE

I understand what's wrong with this. I can't decide what $A$ and $B$ are because they might not actually even by numbers. The function $h$ assigns them numbers to cover everything. Kind of like a room of boys and girls and $f$ maps to all of the boys, and $g$ maps to all the girls? $h$ will map to the union, which is the entire room hence it is surjective.

Comment: It appears from that last update that you now have the right idea about what needs to be proved. The task then becomes to find a way to use the given surjections $f$ and $g$ to construct $h$; this is what I’ve outlined in my answer.

Answer (score 3):

HINT: You are supposed to be proving a general theorem about *all* pairs of sets $A$ and $B$ such that there are surjections $f:\Bbb N\to A$ and $g:\Bbb N\to B$, so you are not free to choose specific sets $A$ and $B$. Thus, your argument gets off very much on the wrong foot.

It *is* useful, however, to look at the sets $\Bbb N_e=\{2n:n\in\Bbb N\}$ and $\Bbb N_o=\{2n+1:n\in\Bbb N\}$. Note that there are bijections

$$\varphi:\Bbb N_e\to\Bbb N:n\mapsto\frac{n}2$$

and

$$\psi:\Bbb N_o\to\Bbb N:n\mapsto\frac{2n-1}2\;.$$

- Verify that $\varphi$ and $\psi$ are bijections.
- Show that $f\circ\varphi$ is a surjection from $\Bbb N_e$ to $A$.
- Show that $g\circ\psi$ is a surjection from ... ?
- Use the previous two points to construct a surjection from $\Bbb N$ to $A\cup B$.

Comment: Ok... So the original functions are like giving numbers to elements in the set, which may or may not be actual numbers... The new function just takes them both together to cover both sets..?

Comment: @J.S.R.: Yes, but the trick is to combine the numbering functions $f$ and $g$, both of which have domain $\Bbb N$, to get a single function with domain $\Bbb N$ that numbers $A\cup B$.

Comment: Do I **have** to compose functions here?

Comment: @J.S.R.: I don’t immediately see any alternative. There are slightly different ways to implement the same basic idea, but all of them involve composing $f$ and $g$ with other functions.

Comment: The compositions are surjections because $f$ and $g$ are surjections, correct? Suppose we were trying to construct an injection union $h$. Then the functions that were being composed with would have to be at least injective, right? (I don't know those greek letters or their LaTeX inputs)

Comment: @J.S.R.: You can’t hope to guarantee that $h$ is injective, because $f$ and $g$ need not be. For instance, if $A=\{a\}$ and $B=\{b\}$, then $f(n)=a$ for each $n\in\Bbb N$, and $g(n)=b$ for each $n\in\Bbb N$.

Comment: I just submitted an answer to the question if you can take a look at it. It's by no means a comprehensive answer but I'm trying to grasp the concep.

Answer (score 1):

@Brian M. Scott

Shouldn't $\mathbb{N}_o = \{2n -1: n \in \mathbb{N}\}$? Otherwise this will not output $1$.

Let's assume I already verified that $l: \mathbb{N}_e \rightarrow \mathbb{N}$ and $m: \mathbb{N}_o \rightarrow \mathbb{N}$ are bijections.

Then $f \circ l : \mathbb{N}_e \rightarrow A$

$g \circ m: \mathbb{N}_o \rightarrow B$

$h(n) = $

$f(l(n))$ if $n \in \mathbb{N}_e$

$g(m(n))$ if $n \in \mathbb{N}_o$

These composite functions will send the even and odd numbers to $A$ and $B$, respectively. This piecewise function $h$ which includes both thereby is surjective for all of $A \cup B$. (This is not my proof I'm just outlining my thoughts.

Are the functions supposed to be something like

$f(\frac{l(n)}{2})$ if $n \in \mathbb{N}_e$? That's one of the things that confused me. I don't often use the "$\mapsto$" notation in proofs if you can believe it, so this throws me off when it's used on functions.

---

UPDATE

$l(x) = 2x$

$m(x) = 2x-1$

Surjectivity-

If $n \in \mathbb{N}_e$

$h(n) = f(x) $

If $n \in \mathbb{N}_e$

$h(n) = g(x)$, which is surjective.

Comment: In the notation that I use, $0\in\Bbb N$, so $\{2n+1:n\in\Bbb N\}$ does include $1$. (It’s not important, but you can get $\varphi$ and $\psi$ with `\varphi` and `\psi`, respectively. More generally, of you right click on any mathematical expression, then click on **Show Math As** and **TeX Commands** in the context menus, you’ll get a popup showing the code used to generate the expression.) Yes, your $h$ works. If you recall that technically $f\circ\varphi$ and $g\circ\psi$ are subsets of $\Bbb N_e\times A$ and $\Bbb N_o\times B$, you can write $h$ simply as $(f\circ\varphi)\cup(g\circ\psi)$.

Comment: I posted a proof of the surjectivity of $h$ which I hope holds.

Comment: No, you’ve wandered pretty far off the path now. You want $\ell:\Bbb N_e\to\Bbb N$ to be the function $\ell(n)=\frac{n}2$, and $m:\Bbb N_o\to\Bbb N$ to be the function $m(n)=\frac{m+1}2$ (if your $\Bbb N$ does not include $0$). (That’s all that the notation $\mapsto$ in my answer means; it has nothing to do with the implication arrow that you may have seen used in proofs.) Now you can define $h:\Bbb N\to A\cup B$ by $h(n)=f(\ell(n))$ if $n$ is even, and $h(n)=g(m(n))$ if $n$ is odd. To prove that $h$ is surjective, let $x\in A\cup B$ be arbitrary. If $x\in A$, then $x=f(n)$ for some ...

Comment: ... $n\in\Bbb N$, and I leave it to you to check that $x=h(2n)$. If $x\in B$, then $x=g(n)$ for some $n\in\Bbb N$, and I leave it to you to check that $x=h(2n-1)$. Thus, every $x\in A\cup B$ is $h(n)$ for some $n\in\Bbb N$, and $h$ is therefore surjective.

Comment: ... I'm getting all of my $n$'s and $x$'s mixed up here. I'm used to having a particular function $f(x)$ and choosing a specific $x$ which contains $y$ such that $f(x) = y$.

For example hypothetically $f(x) = 2x + 2$. $x = \frac{y-2}{2}$.

$f(x) = 2*\frac{y-2}{2} + 2 = y$

Comment: Oops: there’s a nasty typo in the comment beginning *No*. It should define $m(n)=\frac{n+1}2$.

Comment: I shouldn't have introduced the notation for even and odd numbers and just said "if n is odd/even" because it took me a long time after looking at the functions to realize how numbers were getting mapped to (I know you covered this)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/40763/discussion-between-j-s-r-and-brian-m-scott).

Comment: Yes, you could define $h(n)=f\left(\frac{n}2\right)$ if $n$ is even, and $h(n)=g\left(\frac{n+1}2\right)$ if $n$ is odd; you’d end up doing exactly the same work to show that this is a well-defined surjection to $A\cup B$. The advantage is that you introduce less notation; the disadvantage is that you do all of the necessary manipulations at once instead of breaking them up into simpler pieces. I can’t stick around right now, I’m afraid: I need to leave the computer for a bit to take care of some chores.

Answer (score 0):

Let $h$ send the $n$th odd to $f_n$ and the $n$th even to $g_n$.

Comment: Please expand your answer a bit more!